# Why can't I print a 2d array if the rows and columns have a difference greater than 1?

Tags: c++, for-loop, pointers, reverse

I have created a program that takes user input for the amount of rows and columns they want generated in a 2d array. The program then takes that array and reverses the order of the rows only. Everything seems to work just fine, but when I enter the amount of rows and columns, if the difference between those two integers is greater than 1, the code breaks. I am a beginner with C++ so I'm not entirely sure what is going on here. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
int r;
int rows;
int cols;

cout << "how many rows: ";
cin >> rows;
cout << "\n";
cout << "how many columns: ";
cin >> cols;
cout << "\n";

int** matr = new int* [rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    matr[i] = new int[cols];
}


for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
{
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        r = rand() % 50 - rand() % 50;
        matr[i][j] = r;
        cout << matr[i][j] << " ";
    }
}
cout << "\n\n";

int **ptr = &matr[rows*cols];

for (int j = rows-1; j > -1; j--)
{
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        *ptr = &matr[i][j];
        cout << **ptr << " ";
    }
}
cout << "\n";
}
```

When debugging, the line that visual studio shows me an error that says 'read access violation'. I do not know what it is trying to tell me here but I assume the issue lies within that error.

Comment: You have swapped `rows` and `cols`. The first dimension you should iterate up to `rows`, the second dimension you should iterate up to `cols`.

Comment: You confound row/col when indexing sometime. `matr[i][j]` should be `matr[j][i]` when `j` is for `rows` and `i` for `cols`.

Answer (score 1):

This declaration

```
int **ptr = &matr[rows*cols];
```

does not make a sense.  The expression `&matr[rows*cols]` points to outside the array `matr` that has only `rows` elements.

If you want to revere the order of rows in the array `matr` then you can write

```
for ( int **first = matr, **last = matr + rows; first < --last; ++first )
{
    std::swap( *first, *last );
}
```

and then you can output the array matr as a two-dimensional array using indices.